# toggle tbody of table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, toggle

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="check" value="cash" checked/>cash
  <input type="radio" name="check" value="credit" />credit
</div>

<table>
  <tbody id="cash">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Cash User name:
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" name="cash1" />
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody id="credit">
    <tr>
      <td>
        credit User name:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="credit1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the div tag I am having two radio buttons. By default I have made the radio button named cash checked now. What I want is that when radio button cash is checked tbody with id `cash` is shown  and tbody with id `credit` hidden and when radio button with name credit is checked then tbody with id `credit` is shown and other tbody to be hidden. I have done it with jQuery but I want it to do with Javascript.

Comment: *"I" want to do it* - or you want *"Us"* to do it? Do you have any best try so far?

Comment: wel  i have done it with jquery but i want it in javascript ...i am new to javascript so dnt knw much abt it

Comment: Check this url http://jsfiddle.net/hZBfb/

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to go for a pure CSS solution, than you have to get rid of the `div` around your `radio` buttons

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6w4b/)

```
tbody {
    display: none;
}

input[value="cash"]:checked + input[value="credit"] + table tbody[id="cash"] {
    display: table-row-group;
}

input[value="credit"]:checked + table tbody[id="credit"] {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

> Note: Just make sure you declare some `class` and make these selectors
>   specific, else it will target all the elements in the above
>   combination in the document.

Comment: @user2999062 Did you checked the demo? or did you even read my answer at first place?

Comment: i dnt understand where to give class....i am new to javascrpt...so little confused in it

Comment: @user2999062 there is no JavaScript in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Javascript code, to be written after the HTML:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("check");
for( var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    switch( radios[i].value){
        case "cash":
            radios[i].onclick = function(){
                document.getElementById("credit").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("cash").style.display = 'block';
            };
            break;

        case "credit":
            radios[i].onclick = function(){
                document.getElementById("cash").style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById("credit").style.display = 'block';
            };
            break;
    }

    if( radios[i].checked){
        radios[i].click();
    }
}
```

The code is running at http://jsfiddle.net/2sPGn/

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
function showData(obj) {
    if ( obj.value == "cash") {
        document.getElementById("cash").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("credit").style.display='none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("cash").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("credit").style.display='';
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="check" value="cash" onclick='showData(this);' checked/>cash
    <input type="radio" name="check" value="credit" onclick='showData(this);' />credit
</div>
<table>
    <tbody id="cash">
        <tr>
            <td>Cash User name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="cash1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="credit" style='display:none'>
        <tr>
            <td>credit User name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="credit1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cash,#credit').hide();

     $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
          $('#'+$(this).attr('value')).show();
     });
});
```